# Kivy Buildozer error

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I just copied the source code of app from kivy's website(simple app)
when ı try to do my simple apk it says that:

```
[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant- 
1.9.4/bin/ant failed!
# Command failed: python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always -- 
storage-dir=/home/kivy/Desktop/wsd/.buildozer/android/platform/build apk -- 
bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name 'My Application' --version 0.1 -- 
package org.test.myapp --android_api 19 --minsdk 9 --private 
/home/kivy/Desktop/wsd/.buildozer/android/app --orientation landscape -- 
copy-libs
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Edit your *buildozer.spec* file and change *log_level = 1* to *log_level = 2*. Save the changes. Run *buildozer android clean* and after completion of clean, run *buildozer android debug*.

Comment: 'v1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/Desktop'
cp: cannot stat 'v1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-cp: android/src/blacklist.txt': No such file or directory
cp: warning: source directory '/home/kivy/Desktop' specified more than once
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2'

Comment: now it gives this error when log_level = 2

Comment: *log_level = 2* will generate a detail debug log when you execute *buildozer android debug* in your project folder. Please share your buildozer debug log.

Comment: how can ı get ıt ?

Comment: Copy and paste the buildozer debug log into a txt file or take a *PrtSc* (Print Screen) of the error.

Comment: here is  https://ibb.co/eU7cGn

Comment: As per Print Screen, Cython is missing. Please install Cython, *sudo pip install --upgrade cython==0.25.2*

Comment: but it says its installed https://ibb.co/drDW97

Comment: Where did you save the simple Kivy app in the VM Buildozer?

Comment: on desktop, in a folder, now ım trying to make my app but it's gives these errors and ım using python 3, can it be a problem

Comment: I solved the problem, when ı try to code my app with python 2.7 it is created succesfully, thank you for your help.